# Flutter web performance with getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm using `getx` state management for flutter. I read a few articles ([blog.codemagic.io](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app./), [itnext.io](https://itnext.io/flutter-performance-tips-4580b2491da8)) that explain that we shouldn't use methods for widgets because you can save CPU cycles and use them with a const constructor to make rebuild when only needed and much more benefits.

My question is, Is it necessary to use classes instead of methods when I use `getx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure this out is to actually dive into the code of GetX itself.

If you look at the [`Obx`](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/4ac4e49ea6d7dbef33675c608d71becb0beb7cbd/lib/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart) source code, you will see that `Obx` itself is actually a widget (with a `const` constructor, to boot). So, when you're typing `Obx(...)`, you are **not** calling a helper method, but actually instantiating a widget class.

So, to answer your last question: no, to use GetX you don't need to do any extra `class` wrapping. `Obx` itself is already a Widget class with a `const` constructor.